# how can i bring a window to the top in linux use qt?

Tags: linux, qt

I try to use `QWidget::activatedWindows()`, but it didn't work! So how can I bring the `QWidget` to top level of other windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But `QWidget::raise()` will work.

Answer (score 0):

This will probably work:

```
window->setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
```

Comment: But it is not the result i want to.